# “Switch sites” on data.stackexchange.com: icons and labels for SO and Meta SO are wrong

Tags: bug, data-explorer

When running a stored query on data.stackexchange.com, one can select the StackExchange site to which the query should apply. This functionality is provided by a little search field with a text input that provides a “live search” for the SE sites.

When entering `stacko` in this field, I get (among others) the results *Stack Overflow* and *Meta Stack Overflow*. So far, so good.

But: When I select “*Meta* Stack Overflow”, the (colored) “Stack Overflow” icon appears, and the icon hover text says “Stack Overflow”. The query, however, is applied to “Meta Stack Overflow”. It's the same the other way round; selecting “Stack Overflow” shows the icon and label text for Meta, while the query refers to Stack Overflow.

I hope I'm not the only one to experience this. If more details should be required, please let me know.

(By the way, small UI feedback: The site selection field should probably be above the submit button, as it's an element of the form to be submitted.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon is *not for the current site*, but a shortcut to switch between the main site and the child meta.

The icon is *part of the site switch control*; either click the icon, *or* use the search box to switch to a different site altogether:

> [image: switch sites]

The tooltip on the icon also indicates that clicking it will switch:

> [image: icon tooltip]

The current site is shown in the top right, above the query text box.

Comment: Ok, but isn't that highly misleading? Especially as querying the meta sites is (for the vast majority of users, as I would guess) not too interesting?

Comment: @lxg: the label in front is pretty clear about what the icon is for. I personally query meta sites almost as often as the regular sites. The vast majority of users don't care about SEDE in the first place. :-)

Comment: I have interpreted “Switch sites” as label for the input field, and the icon as indicator for the currently selected site. The blue bubble icon did not have a meaning for me, as it is too unspecific. Also, I did not assume a connection to the SO icon, as the blue icon is inside the text box. Maybe the label text should indicate that you can click the icon to toggle. And the text input should have an own text label. Anyway, thanks for the clarification. (And maybe somebody from StackExchange's UI/UX team might want to have a look at this.)

Comment: Hmm, I *was* going to put the current site icon to the left of the label to see if that helped, but I guess I forgot about doing that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The tooltip is actually a part of the problem, it's what got me extra confused. Maybe because I thought that the tooltip is a description for what the button *shows*, not for what it *does*.